# How to turn a column of comma-separated strings into an array of strings

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ddl

I have this table in PostgreSQL with one of the columns being a string containing nconsts called `directors`. The strings are formatted as `nm00386378,nm97284993` and I need to turn each string into an array ex: `{"nm00386378","nm97284993"}`

I tried the following code but I think it just turned the string into a one value array:

```
alter table crew_text
    alter directors drop default,
    alter directors type text[] using array[directors],
    alter directors set default '{}';
```

I got `{"nm00386378,nm97284993"}` for the array values but I'm expecting `{"nm00386378","nm97284993"}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) like so:

```
alter table crew_text
   alter directors drop default
,  alter directors type text[] using string_to_array(directors, ',')
,  alter directors set default '{}';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e14c44a12f986ae22ea63f5de2328206)*

Only resort to regular expression functions when needed. Those are more powerful, but also more tricky and substantially more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `USING` clause for `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER ... TYPE`:

```
USING regexp_split_to_array(directors, ',')
```

Comment: Why use regexp for a simple delimiter split?

Comment: Because no cheaper alternative came to mind. The criticism is of course justified.